# Why won't my page show what it needs to?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I can't see why my page isn't loading what's in the `<h1>` tag in  my `index.js` file.  I'm trying to make a practice app with `ReactJS` but it won't even let me get started.  I've tried many things to rectify this but fell short every single time hence why I'm here.

Here's my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lamda</title>
    <marquee>Welcome to Lamda!</marquee>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.23.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="LamdaPage"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here's my `index.js`

```
var LamdaPage = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
       <div>
        <h1>Why won't this show?</h1>
       </div>
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(<LamdaPage/>, document.getElementById("LamdaPage"));
```

Comment: Your function looks like it's missing a `return` keyword.

Comment: @Pointy Funny thing is... I just noticed that the second I asked this question.  Nonetheless, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that a function must return value. In this case, render function must return value as HTML which you are putting as body of function

```
var LamdaPage = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
       return (<div>
        <h1>Why won't this show?</h1>
       </div>);
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(<LamdaPage/>, document.getElementById("LamdaPage"));
```